# How to hover a whole element to show details

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a 'Portfolio' section which has 2 thumbnails, the first one at the top of the block and the second at the bottom.

This is what I want:
http://i.imgur.com/PRENiPV.png

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12egqxs3/)

There is a problem I do this by hovering on the image placed at the bottom, it has a `margin-top: 200px` then when I just hover it I just removed those `margin-top:0;` this is not what I want, I would like to make a hover effect with the whole element, if you hove either the image on top or the image on bottom, the hover effect activates.

If you guys give me a better structure with very valids arguments I can change mine :)

I leave my HTML and CSS Below so you guys can help me to figure out how to solve this.

HTML:

```
           <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <a class="portfolio-image" href="#">
                        <div class="portfolio-image-one">
                            <img src="../img/portfolioweb/1.jpg" alt="Thumbnail" />
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a class="portfolio-info" href="#">
                        <div class="portfolio-logo-one">
                            <img src="../img/portfolioweb/1l.jpg" alt="Logo" />
                        </div>
                        <p class="porfolio-brief-info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus nam nobis consectetur.</p>

                        <p class="portfolio-info-link">Learn More</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.portfolio-web
{
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.portfolio-container
{
    margin: 40px 0;
}
.portfolio-tagline
{
    font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px 0;
}
.portfolio-item
{
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 280px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.portfolio-image
{
    cursor: default;
}
.portfolio-image-one
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
.portfolio-info
{
    background: white;
    margin-top: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 280px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.portfolio-info:hover
{
    margin-top: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.portfolio-logo-one
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.porfolio-brief-info
{
    color: #909090;
    font: 13px/20px 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
.portfolio-info-link
{
    color: #ff8e01;
    font: 14px/20px 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achieving hover effect over whole element, you can use CSS combinator:

```
.portfolio-item:hover > .portfolio-info
{
    margin-top: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

instead of

```
.portfolio-info:hover
{
    margin-top: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this fetchs perfecly well, just one question, why did you use the ">" symbol, what does that refers to in the css, thank you so much again!

Comment: It indicates child selector. So the CSS will be applied to child elements defined after ">" symbol.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12egqxs3/4/)

**CSS**

```
.portfolio-item:hover > .portfolio-info
{
    color: #909090;
    font: 13px/20px 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;

    /* ADDED */
    position: absolute;
}

.portfolio-info-link
{
color: #ff8e01;
font: 14px/20px 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 10px; 
padding-top: 100px; /*Increased to accommodate wrapped text */
font-weight: bold;
}
```